# What does semicolon mean in the imap statement?

Tags: key-bindings, external-command

For the statement:

```
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!python % <CR>
```

When you press `F5` key in insert mode,the current python file saved and executed by python.

Someone write another statement:

```
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:!python % [filename.py]; <CR>
```

`:` means to end the current command and start a new command.What does `;` mean here?What the total statement means ?

Comment: Not sure what the `[filename.py]` part is supposed to be... But the `;` is a shell command separator, you can do `echo hello; date; grep xyz abc.txt` etc. Adding a single `;` at the end of a shell command typically does nothing, it's the separator with no command afterwards. Not sure why someone would add it here, but that's my read of what this does...

Comment: Also note that this is not related to `imap` or anything... It's just part of what gets passed to `:!` to run as an external shell command.